# On Button Click checkbox checked validation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, checkbox

I have a scenario, where I display data in a `Gridview`. Now what I want is, There are two buttons as `Approve` and `Reject`. I want to validate that atleast one checkbox should be checked before clicking on one of the `buttons`.

Below is my HTML.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDisplayCMMData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="heavyTable table" EmptyDataText="No records to display"
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="grdDisplayCMMData_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SAP_ID" HeaderText="Sap Id" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="ID_OD" HeaderText="ID to OD" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE" HeaderText="ID to OD Change" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE" HeaderText="ID to OD Change Date" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RRH_COUNTCHANGE" HeaderText="RRH Count Change" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RRH_CHANGEDDATE" HeaderText="RRH Count Change Date" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE" HeaderText="Tenancy Count Change" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE" HeaderText="Tenancy Changed Date" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS" HeaderText="Current Status" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve/Reject">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprRejCMM" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<div class="text-center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnApproveCMM" Text="Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btnApproveCMM_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRejectCMM" Text="Reject" runat="server" OnClick="btnRejectCMM_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

Also see my `OnClick` event of Approve.

```
protected void btnApproveCMM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IPColoFields ObjIPColoFields = new App_Code.IPColoFields();
        List<IPColoBilling.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails> UMSGroupDetails = (List<IPColoBilling.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails>)Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"];

        Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"] = UMSGroupDetails;
        string strApprove = "";

        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in grdDisplayCMMData.Rows)
        {
            var checkbox = gvrow.FindControl("chkApprRejCMM") as CheckBox;

                if (checkbox.Checked)
                {
                    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(grdDisplayCMMData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);

                    ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id = Id;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_ID = intCurrentGrpId;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_NAME = strCurrentGrp;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_ID = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupID;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_NAME = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupName;
                    ObjIPColoFields.FCA_STATUS = "1";
                    ObjIPColoFields.LAST_UPDATED_BY = lblUserName.Text;
                    strApprove = CommonDB.Approve_IPCOLO_CMMLevel(ObjIPColoFields);
                }                                                         
         }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record Approved successfully'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
        BindCMMData();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string strErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString() + " " + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        CommonDB.WriteLog("ERROR:" + strErrorMsg, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPCOLO_LOG"].ToString());
    }
}
```

I tried the logic of getting the count of checkbox and if it is less than `0` then prompt an error. But in Checkbox there is no such property of getting the count.

Please suggest any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a CustomValidator.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="countCheckBoxes" 
    ErrorMessage="Check at least one"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And then the function to test if there are any checkboxes checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function countCheckBoxes(oSrc, args) {
        var cnt = $('<%# GridView1.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
        args.IsValid = cnt > 0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: let me try and check this. but will it apply for Reject also ?

Comment: It is for both Buttons. If you want only for Approve you need to use the same `ValidationGroup` on both the Validator and Button. If you want for both buttons then give all three the same ValidationGroup (or none if there are no more buttons on the page).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps.

1. Add some random classname as "XYZ" to your Checkbox

> `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprRejCMM" runat="server" Class="xyz" />`

2.add OnClientClick event to button

```
> <asp:Button ID="btnApproveCMM" Text="Approve" runat="server"
> OnClick="btnApproveCMM_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick
> = "javascript:return CheckData(); " />
```

3.Using Jquery check whether atleast one checkbox is checked and return false if non is sleected inside CheckData function.

> `
>
> `
>   if($('input.xyz:checked').length >0) {return false;} else return true;

`

`
If function returns false then postback will not happen.